# How to select a vertical block with exceeding lines?

Tags: vim, selection, vertical-text

In Vim you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to select a vertical block of code. This is pretty cool, as this way you can insert a rectangular block of text anywhere in your text. A feature I haven't seen anywhere else yet.

But say I have a text like:

```
1 abcde
2 abcdefg
3 abcdefg
4 abc
```

I want to select this full block as vertical block. If I'm on the `a` of line 1, and start selection, then move down to line 4, I can only move the cursor to the last character `c` in that line. So the lines above are cut off, giving me this selection:

```
1 abc
2 abc
3 abc
4 abc
```

Is there a way to get the full text selected as vertical block?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to select exact  4 lines (including the 1st line), you could:

`Ctrl-V$3j`

this selects all the texts, but they are not really in a "block", because the first line and the last line have different length.

If you do want have a "block" of text, (appending spaces on those "shorter" lines), you could:

```
set ve=all
Ctrl-V hhhhh... jjjjj...
```

by setting `ve` to `all`, your cursor could go anywhere. If you like after the selection/copying, you could set the `ve` back to its original value.

Answer (score 1):

A minute after asking this question i found it out myself. The trick is to press <kbd>$</kbd> on line 4 above. So the full series of keystrokes, if the cursor is on the `a` of line 1 is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty solution is to insert 4 spaces a the end of line 4.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, too. But it's way easier: Check my own answer ;).